# Is hiding the ios safari navbar by scrolling body the only way?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, mobile-safari

I have a website with a grid layout:
Header: fixed height, always showing on top.
Content: All content goes here and it scrollable.
Footer: Fixed height, always showing on bottom.

I set the body to height: 100% and I make the content div to scroll any overflow. However since I don't scroll the body the bottom navbar or the url bar on ios safari never goes away even when scrolling the content.

Do I have to have scrolling on the body?

Answer (score 0):

try adding "position: sticky" to the footer and nav-bar in css.